# Angular UI router resolve undefined in controller when return data in factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I am using Angular Ui router, when returning a factory in resolve getting undefined in controller. Whats wrong here? Why getting undefined when return a factory call?

**working when return a string:**
When return a simple string in resolve function, getting a data in controller.

**Factory call**

```
app.factory('LogHomService', function(Service1, Service2) {
  return {
    MyService: function(data) {
      Service1.log("user", encodeURIComponent("ad"))
        .then(function(response) {
          var FullUrl = response.strURL;
          var objs = response.products;
          Service2.pageLoad(objs)
            .then(function(response) {
              var homeScreen = response;
              data(homeScreen);
            });
        });
    },
  };
});
```

UI router:

```
.state('home.prod', {
  url: '/product',
  views: {
    '@': {
      templateUrl: baseUrl + 'home/product',
      controller: 'productController'
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    param2: function(LogHomService) {
      return LogHomService.MyService();
    }
  }
})
```

Controller:

```
var productController = function ($scope, $rootScope, $state, $stateParams,param2)
{
       console.log(param2); // getting undefined
}
CashController.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$state','$stateParams','param2');
```

Comment: I think this happens because you're not returning the promise from your factory. Try adding a return like: `return Service1.log("user", ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Within your definition for `MyService()` method you do not return anything. As a result the value injected in controller from `resolve` is `undefined`. Try changing your code to return a `promise/ value` from the `MyService()` method

```
MyService: function(data) {
  return Service1.log("user", encodeURIComponent("ad"))
    .then(function(response) {
      var FullUrl = response.strURL;
      var objs = response.products;
      Service2.pageLoad(objs)
        .then(function(response) {
          var homeScreen = response;
          data(homeScreen);
        });
    });
},
```

Comment: when return a service1 , getting a response in controller, the problem occurs when return in service 2 call getting undefined.  but service 2 response have values http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37769380/angular-ui-router-resolve-undefined-in-controller-when-return-data-in-factory